# Blur not working - Angular 2

Tags: angular, blur

I'm trying to set a blue event in angular 2 like so:

```
<div id="area-button" (blur)="unfocusAreaInput()" class="form-group" (click)="focusAreaInput()">
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleplaceDirective } from 'angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-area',
    directives: [GoogleplaceDirective],
    templateUrl: 'app/find-page/area-picker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/find-page/area-picker.component.css']
})
export class AreaComponent {
    public address: Object;
    @ViewChild('areaInput') areaInput;
    areaSelected: boolean = false;
    @Output() onAreaSelected = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    @Output() onAreaDeselected = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    constructor(el: ElementRef) { }
    getAddress(place: Object) {
        this.address = place['formatted_address'];
        var location = place['geometry']['location'];
        var lat = location.lat();
        var lng = location.lng();
        console.log("Address Object", place);
    }

    focusAreaInput() {
        this.areaInput.nativeElement.focus();
        this.onAreaSelected.emit(true);
    }

        unfocusAreaInput() {
        this.onAreaSelected.emit(false);
    }
}
```

unfocusAreaInput() never gets executed. Why?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your `blur` event is not working because your `div` can't receive focus in the first place. If you add `tabindex="1"` (1 can be replaced with any number) or `contentEditable` (this will make div's content editable) to your `div`, it will be able to receive focus and then `blur` event will work. Plus, you can then use `focus` instead of `click`.

Comment: not working, (blur) on div even after setting tabindex=0, the div also contains ngIf, is that matters?

Comment: This doesn't work...is there an updated answer?  This shouldn't be marked as the answer unless a working example is shown.

Comment: That's not working because div is not focused when initialized anyway.
I have added window.document.getElementById('container').focus() in my ngOnInit() and then it works. Needed to outline: 0 in css for div as well.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try `(focusout)="unfocusAreaInput()"` on your `div`. That will fire when any focusable element inside the div loses focus (incl. when the element is removed) and some other element in the `div` isn't simultaneously focused.

If you want to know what element lost focus inside your `div`, you can pass that in like so: `(focusout)="unfocusAreaInput($event.target)"`.

More information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event

Answer (score 3):

Use `tabindex` property with it.
Setting

```
tabindex="0"
```

will give it highest priority in getting focus thus your `blur` event will work

Comment: (blur) not working on div even after setting the tabindex=0